# How can I add values found in a Database to a series of Dropdown Buttons?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlcommand

I have an app which sends texts to clients, and I'd like to be able to provide a templating system for it; the completed code will fill a toolStripDropDownButton with values from my Database, providing a description from the database, then when the user clicks the description, the text to be sent box will be pre-filled with template text from the database.

I have made a start by testing this code using a messagebox, however the code will not compile as there is an error at line 62 saying "no overload for method 'GetValues' takes 0 Arguments", I'd like some guidance on how I could get my code working if possible please.

offending code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        panel1.Hide();
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:CRUSADER,49172;Initial Catalog=HermesSMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Admin;Password=w");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        comm.CommandText = ("Select Description FROM Templates");
        SqlDataReader DR = comm.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show(DR.GetValues()ToString());<-line 62
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know what the error is if you don't include that in the question?

Comment: DR.GetValues().ToString()  You are missing a . before `ToString()`

Comment: sorry yes, of course! the error is "No overload for method 'GetValues' takes 0 arguments"

Comment: After your proposed amendment

Comment: @Reece Isn't that message clear enough? You are calling `GetValues()` - i.e. supplying no arguments to it and it requires arguments. I suggest you check out the documentation before posting these types of questions. They will answer them for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no overload for method 'GetValues' takes 0 Arguments

Well, that's because there's no overload for [the `GetValues` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues.aspx) which takes zero arguments.  It requires an array of `object`s to be passed to the method.  Take a look at the example in the linked MSDN documentation:

```
Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);
```

An `Object[]` argument is passed to the `GetValues` method, and that array will then be populated with the values from the `SqlDataReader`.

As an aside, I really recommend taking a more strongly-typed approach to data access.  Ideally using something like Entity Framework or even the deprecated (yet still quite functional) Linq to Sql.  Boxing everything into an untyped `object` results in a lot of type checking code and a high potential for errors.

Comment: doesn't that just get the value pertaining to the number of columns rather than the values contained in them?

Comment: @Reece: It does both.  It returns the count, and modifies the `object` collection.  (Admittedly, I *really* don't like methods which modify parameters like that.  It can be an unintuitive side-effect and makes the method invocation unclear.  But that's what they did in this method.)